# How can I use variables at condition expressions on templates in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, multistage-pipeline

I have multiple pipelines that are being built from a multistage yaml (extends: template:)
and i want to set conditions on which jobs and steps should run when i pass a variable.
So in this case i want to set the variable 'Migrations=false' and skip some jobs (Migration job) and some steps (npm run integration-tests) on my integration Job

I have tried to use (to skip migration jobs on migration.yaml)

```
stages:
- stage: dev
  displayName: dev
  jobs:
  - ${{if ne(variables.migrations, 'false')}}:
    - template: /Dotnet/Release/migration.yaml
```

and also (to skip integration script on integration.yaml)

```
 jobs:
 - template: /Dotnet/Release/integration.yaml
   parameters:
     migrations: ${{ variables.Migrations }}

###integration.yaml###
- name: 'migrations'
  default: 'true'
  type: string
jobs:
- job: Integration
  steps:  
   - script: "echo step1"
   - ${{if ne(parameters.migrations, 'false')}}:
     - script: npm run integration-tests
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example:

```
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - bash: echo "A"


- stage: B
  variables:
    someVar: true
  jobs:
  - job: B
    steps:
    - ${{ if ne(variables['someVar'], 'false') }}:
      - template: resource-template.yml
    - script: echo hi
  - template: test.yml
    parameters:
      migrations: ${{ variables.someVar }}


#test.yml

parameters:
- name: 'migrations'
  default: 'false'
  type: string

jobs:
- job: Integration
  steps:  
  - script: "echo step1"
  - ${{ if ne(parameters.migrations, 'true') }}:
      - script: echo hello
```

**Note:**

You may get red wavy line (like the screenshot below) when you create the yaml file. But the schema is correct, you can run it without issue.

[image]

Comment: The subtitution of the variable Migrations it si being taking as null when the pipeline initializate so it takes  the default value that in my case is 'true'.


 jobs:
 - template: /Dotnet/Release/integration.yaml
   parameters:
     migrations: ${{ variables.Migrations }}